# need help in adding options to select using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I have a page layout like the below and I need to set values in `<select>` as I have a form.

[image]

```
<form action="add.jsp">
    <input name="title" id="title"/>
    <input name="company" id="company" />           
    <select name="options" id="options">

    </select>           
    <button>Submit</button>

</form>
```

I want to add values to above `<select/>` from the checkboxes out side of the form which are

```
<input id="input-checkbox-1" name="input-checkbox" type="checkbox">Option 1
<input id="input-checkbox-2" name="input-checkbox" type="checkbox">Option 2
<input id="input-checkbox-3" name="input-checkbox" type="checkbox">Option 3
```

now don't have any idea of how to get values from checkboxes and add options to select using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now don't have any idea of how to get values from checkboxes and add options to select using jQuery.

First, to get an HTML element, you can use `$("css selector")`, `document.getElementById("id value")`, or `document.querySelector("css selector")`.

Here's a CSS selector syntax reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

Next, to retrieve the value of a checkbox, you can refer to the `.checked` property of the element. It will be `true` if the box is checked and `false` otherwise.

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("change",function(){
  alert(this.checked);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />Check me
```

Finally, to add a value to a `select` element, create an `option` element, set its text and value, and add it to the `select`.

```js
var select = document.querySelector("select");
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]');
for(var i = 0, len = checkboxes.length; i < len; i++){
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener("change",addOrRemoveMe);
}
function addOrRemoveMe(){
  if(this.checked){
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = this.name;
    option.text = this.name;
    select.appendChild(option);
  }else{
    select.removeChild(select.querySelector('[value="'+this.name+'"]'));
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="One"/> One<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Two"/> Two<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Three"/> Three<br/>
<select></select>
```

Comment: Thanks for great help, but when I submit the form I con't get values from the `select` box, I guess those values are not selected as I'm setting it as a hidden field, how can I make those options selected.

Comment: Add One line `option.selected = 'selected';` after `option.text = this.name;`, I hope this solves issue.

Comment: @ArshadAli as you said it Solved my issue, thanks to Thriggle, he saved my life.